# extracting values from log files mached with reges in a simpler way, and more elegant, than grep-while-prinf

Tags: bash, grep, printf

I have few log files that look like:

```
#LOGa# 180.149.126.169 ## 85 with value 350.00000000000000000000 due brand: 350.00000000000000000000 country: 0 {2020-11-26_11-01-00}
#DETAILS_hits# 180.149.126.169 ## hits=([brand/17]="1" [brand/18]="1" [no_brand]="1" ) {2020-11-26_11-01-00}
#LOG_brand# 180.149.126.169 ## BRANDS=([anyBrand]="1" ) {2020-11-26_11-01-00}
#LOG_country# 180.149.126.169 ## COUNTRY=([anyCountry/17]="1" [anyContinent/18]="1" ) {2020-11-26_11-01-00}
```

and I want to extract dome values of some especific Log lines

sure I can go with

```
grep -HiRE "(#LOGa#)(.+)(## )(.+)" --include \myFile.log | while read _ ip _ rank _ value _ _ valueBrand _ _ valueCountry _ ; do printf "%.0f %.0f\n" $valueBrand $valueCountry; done
```

but isn't a more elegant way,
somethign like

```
cleanME myFile.log "(#LOGa#)($ip)(## )($rank)(with value)($value)(due brand:)($valueBrand)(country:)($valueCountry)(.*)" "$valueBrand.0f $valueCountry.0f"
```

sure I can go building a function like this, but I short of remember that it was better ways to do that than grep + while + printf

Comment: Could you please do add sample expected output in your question for better understanding of question.

Comment: Why not just `awk`? `isn't a more elegant way` What exactly is your question? "Elegant" may be opinion based. We don't know what you "short of remember".

Answer (score 1):

If `Perl` happens to be your option, would you please try:

```
perl -ne '/^#LOGa#\s+([\d.]+)\s+##\s+([\d.]+)\s+with value\s+([\d.]+)\s+due brand:\s+([\d.]+)\s+country:\s+([\d.]+)/ && printf "%.0f %.0f\n", $4, $5' myFile.log
```

Output for the provided input:

```
350 0
```

- The option `-n` tells `Perl` to process the input file line by line as `sed`.
- The option `-e` enables a one-liner.
- The syntax `/regex/ && printf ...` prints the arguments only if the line
  matches the regex as `grep`.
- The parens within the regex create capture group and the matched substrings
  can be referred with `$1`, `$2`, ... in order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is any better, but consider this:

```
find . -type f -name myFile.log -print | xargs sed -En 's/^#LOGa# .+ ## .+ with value [0-9.-]+ due brand: ([0-9.-]+) country: ([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/1;Tx;p;:x'
```

Explanation:

`find` -- recursively find in the current directory (`.`) all files (`-type f`) with the name myFile.log (`-name myFile.log`) and `-print` them. (`sed` does not have a `-R` option like `grep`.) Pipe this to `xargs` which will, for each one, invoke the stream editor `sed`, with extended regexp syntax (`-E`) and no automatic printing of lines (`-n`). Substitute (`s//`) the given regexp, using grouping operators to capture the valueBrand and valueCountry, and substituting for the whole line these two values captured in parentheses (`\1 \2`) in the first occurrence (`/1`). Then if this substitution does not happen, jump to label x (`;Tx`); otherwise `p`rint the line. Then the label x (`;:x`) and end (just exits).

I'm not sure if you are intentionally truncating the decimal places in the output or not; to do that you'd have to pass it through a `bash` `printf` statement (`while read a b; do printf "%.0f %.0f" a b; done`) or some other program, or do it another way. Or if you really want to truncate (i.e. not round) to zero decimal places, you could use `brand: ([0-9-]+)\.[0-9]*`  instead of `brand: ([0-9.-]+)` . This just excludes the decimal point and mantissa from the string and drops it.